# Webview not properly sized Jetpack compose (Autosizing Webview Composable)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I need to use WebView in place of `Text` composable (to display complex text and maths). Size of the `WebView` will depend on amount of content(text). But currently it only works when a fixed size modifier is applied. Without fixed size; WebView stutters while loading and many times it wont even show up.

I am loading content using `loadWithBaseUrl()` method.
I have tried using `WebView` composable from Accompanist library; Also tried my custom implementation; but it still wont work.

```kotlin
// implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-webview:0.24.3-alpha'

    LazyColumn(){
        item {
            val webViewState = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = FakeData.HTML_DOC)
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 8.dp).height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            ) {
                WebView(
                    state = webViewState,
                    modifier = Modifier
//                        .size(400.dp, 200.dp)  // When fixed size applied problem disappears
                )
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have a similar issue when trying to fit the WebView into a column with some other Composables. I made some progress on this by using `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` but it's still flaky. Have you filed an issue in the Accompanist GitHub?

Comment: Hello @Paul T. I have filed the issue just now. Feel free to suggest an improvement. here's the link: https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1224

Answer (score 0):

Use custom `AccompanistWebViewClient`, override `onPageFinished`, you can get webPage height by `evaluateJavascript`.

```
val jsWebHeight = "(function() {\n" +
                        "\tvar body = document.body,\n" +
                        "\thtml = document.documentElement;\n" +
                        "\tvar height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);\n" +
                        "\tvar width = html.scrollWidth;\n" +
                        "\tif (width > 0) return height;\n" +
                        "\telse return 0;\n" +
                        "})();"
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
     super.onPageFinished(view, url)

     view?.let{ webView ->
          val width = webView.width
          if (width > 0) {
               webView.evaluateJavascript(jsWebHeight) { result ->
                    result?.toIntOrNull()?.let { height ->
                         if (height > 0) {
                              // set webView height here, height is dp unit
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```